# Users Principle/Identityis overridden by second browser instance in aspnet identity MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using aspnet identity/owin for authentication/Authorization in my application.

Problem when I login using second aplication user from new browser instance while first one is already logged in, second browser is probabily overriding the User principle/identiy obejects. Due to this first browse user is getting logged out as second user has less previliges tha first user.

My question is why not each browser instance is maintaining its user principle/identity? I am doing sometinng wrong in code? please help. This issue is buggign me for many days.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName) }, 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
            ClaimTypes.Name, 
            ClaimTypes.Role);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles));

var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

// Set current principal
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

//User Added code 
await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

//set up cookie for using data across pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em.. where did you get this way of working with Idnetity? this looks broken on many levels.

First of all, remove `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;` - probably this is causing a lot of troubles. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not always a user that is logged in into MVC application. Sometimes (on application startup for example) this can be a user under which IIS is running).

If this is a login code, please create a new MVC project in VS 2013 with Individual Accounts and see the code that handles the logging in - just follow that pattern.